# Add custom method and view to entity with EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm new to symfony and I'm using esayAdminBundle on one of my project and I would like to call a custom method and a custom render inside the list view.

The custom view is easy but my problem it's sending data to this block, did I need to use custom action or something else ? I'm lost on this one.

The final view is the entity list on top and my custom render below.

If anyone of you have a solution I'm here to read it ;)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to solve this:

1) You can override the default `list.html.twig` template (entirely or just for one specific entity, as explained here: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/book/3-list-search-show-configuration.md#advanced-design-configuration) and then put a `render(controller(...))` call in that template to execute your controller.

2) You could create a custom menu item that points to a specific route of your application (as explained here: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/book/6-menu-configuration.md). In that controller you execute anything you need and the result is to render a custom template which again extends from the default `list.html.twig` (to not lose the "list" feature and after that you put your own code).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer i try this and i come back here if i need :)
And thank you for your bundle it's really easy to use for beginner like me

Comment: I accepted your answer i tried with a    render(controller(...))    method and it worked like i wanted